# Sorting Issue in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to sort a list which I have imported from a file in Python, however I am having no luck, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
fr = open("database_results\Class_" + option + ".txt", 'r')
lines = [line for line in fr if line.strip()]
fr.close()
lines.sort(key=int)
fw = open("database_results\Class_" + option + ".txt", 'w')
fw.writelines(lines)
print(lines)
print("ALERT: File successfully sorted numerically!")
```

The reason I am splitting the lines like this is because the data is stored like this in the database:

```
[Name: 'John Smith' Score: '7']
[Name: 'Mitchel Jones' Score: '5']
```

I want the file to be sorted so the people who have received the highest score are put to the top of the list. For the example above, this would be formatted fine, because John has a higher score than Mitchel.

Comment: Stop rolling back, the *Thanks in advance* is not required. It is considered noise here.

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't want to be rude.

Comment: What do the actual lines look like?

Comment: "The reason I am splitting the lines like this"? How? You aren't splitting the lines at all.

Comment: "I am having no luck" - another stellar error description.

Comment: ["[Name: 'John Smith' Score: '7']\n", "[Name: 'Mitchel Jones' Score: '5']\n",

Comment: You are using the `key` argument incorrectly. [Have you tried reading the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line: lines = [line for line in fr if line.strip()]

Comment: Hi Tom, I have done a alphabetical sort and used this function, so wanted to use the same one with the list for numerical. I am quite new to Python so I wanted to experiment, however I find myself very lost here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You're using the key argument of sort wrong. Key specifies what part of each item in your list is being used to sort. In my example, I'm supplying an anonymous function which is saying that for each item in `l`, use the value at index 0 for determining sort order

```
l = [
    [3,1,2],
    [1,5,2],
    [0,9,3],
    [2,5,2]
]
l.sort(key=lambda x : x[0])
print l # prints [[0, 9, 3], [1, 5, 2], [2, 5, 2], [3,1,2]]
```

2) In order to do your sort, you'll likely need to perform a split on each line, identify which index the score is sitting in, and cast it to an int. This should do the sort:

`lines.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x : int(x.strip().split('Score: ')[1].replace(']', '').replace('"', "").replace("'", "")))`

Here's what's happening:

1. Split the string on score so we get back `["[Name: Blah Blah", "10]"]`
2. We grab the item from the new list where the score is sitting (index 1)
3. Replace the ], ', and " characters so we don't fail our int cast
4. Cast the score to an int for numeric sorting

3) Probably not the best idea to write from the same file you were just reading from. It would be better to put it somewhere like `"database_results\Class_{0}_sorted.txt".format(option)"`